# Functional Choice for p in a Bernoulli Distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, bernoulli-numbers

Why is the functional choice $p = \exp(x)/(1+\exp(x))$ to model $p$ a good one in a Bernoulli distribution?

Is it because it is limited at $0$ as $x$ approaches $0$ and $1$ as $x$ approaches infinity?

Comment: Is it because it is limited at 0 as x approaches 0 and 1 as x approaches infinity?

Comment: $\frac{\exp(0)}{1+\exp(0)} = \frac12 \not = 0$. Perhaps you were thinking of the limit when $x \to -\infty$

Comment: Yes, my mistake. Is that why it is a good functional choice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logistic and logit transformations have advantages such as:

- (as you identified) symmetric in a sense between (0,1) and the whole real line
- analytically tractable: integral and derivatives have closed forms
- a natural log-odds interpretation: $x=\log\left(\frac{p}{1-p}\right)$
- the logistic distribution being close to a normal distribution (in practice logit and probit models produce very similar results apart from a scale factor on some of the parameters)